# Classloader not 'loading' jar at runtime?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

To start of, its was all working, and sundenly it just stopped and i truly have no idea if i done something to it or there is a problem somewhere else.

My classloader should load a jar file at runtime but apparently it doesn't.

```
String url   = "https://" + serverHost + "/" + getJarPath() + "se.jar";
log.info("http url is: " +url);
String https = url.replaceAll("\\s","");

URL httpsURL = new URL(https);  
log.info("https url is: " + httpsURL);

URLConnection con = httpsURL.openConnection();              
addURL(con.getURL());



private void addURL(URL https) throws IOException { 
        Class<?>[] parameters = new Class[]{URL.class}; 
        // IMPORTANT: MUST use the webapp classloader - so derived extension classes can resolve their base classes
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();        
        // cast to a URL class loader so we can add additional JAR(s) to the search path
        URLClassLoader webappClassLoader = (URLClassLoader)contextClassLoader;  
        Class<?> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

        Method method;
        try {
            method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(webappClassLoader, new Object[]{ https });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "FATAL Exception", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "FATAL Exception", e);
        }
    }
```

I can not disclose the full path of URL but i can confirm 101% the jar is where the String url says, yet i do get DefNotFoundClassException.

Comment: Are you sure there are no proxy preventing downloading the jar? I often get to issue while using office network with proxy required to open http connection.

Comment: @kamoor1982 there are no proxy set + this was working an hour ago, and now just stopped ;o

Comment: What is debug showing? print con.getResponseCode() and see what connection says.

Comment: apparently its 500, so there is some sort of interuption

Comment: Are there any certificate issues connecting with https, and does it work any better with straight http? (Likely not, since you mentioned it was working an hour ago, but still worth asking.) Otherwise, does it work again if you restart Tomcat? I see that you're hacking stuff into the context class loader, but I imagine that the context class loader is effectively static and will accumulate these addURL calls from any previous invocations, so I wonder if any of the previous URLs fed to it could be confusing things, which would get reset with a fresh start?

Comment: HTTP_STATUS 500 means its a server side issue. Try accessing the URL over a browser or use `wget`(linux/cygwin) to see if it works. I dont think there is anything wrong with your code. Except the probability of certificate issue as mentioned by Scott Dudley.